# Downloading all files from an FTP Server

Tags: linux, ftp, debian

I need to download everything from an FTP server to hosting on a different server. I have shell access only to the server I'm downloading the files to. How, using the Linux FTP command, can I download every file, creating the directories needed for them in the process?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use `wget` in this manner (m for mirroring):

```
wget -m ftp://username:password@ip.of.old.host
```

If your username or password contains special characters, you may need to use the format:

```
wget -m --user=username --password=password ftp://ip.of.old.host
```

Alternatively, I found [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-download-all-file-from-ftp-server-recursively.html) which shows you how to do it using ncftp in Debian. You will require root access to the new server if ncftp is not installed already.

In short:

```
sudo apt-get install ncftp
ncftpget –T –R –v –u "ftpuser" ftp.nixcraft.net /home/vivek/backup /www-data
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually had found it myself right before seeing this.  Wasn't using the right google search terms the first five times.

Comment: If you get a "bad port" error message you may have an email address as username (the internet is getting weird) and the @ is confusing wget. Try: wget -m --user some.email@example.com --password myPassword ftp://example.com

Comment: When the password has '@' at the end this does not work. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `ftp`. Here's an example shell script using ftp:

```
#! /bin/bash

ftp -n << 'EOF'
open ftp.your_ftp_host.com
quote USER your_username_here
quote PASS your_password_here
cd gets
prompt no
mget * .
bye
EOF
```

Comment: This solution does not get subdirectory contents

Answer (score 1):

Some FTP servers allow to download whole directories by suffixing their name with .tar or .tgz. The server then creates an archive of that directory.